# Cell renderer and the lost focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using a `JTable` and in order to change the format of numbers. I have extended the `DefaultTableRenderer` class.

In the method `getTableCellRenderedComponent`, I retrun a new `JLabel` with the proper format.
My problem is by doing this the rectangle (border) that underlines the cell which has the focus has disappeared.

Is there a way to get the default border displayed whenever a cell has the focus with my custom render?

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `DefaultTableRenderer` you can call `super()` method and get `Border` from returned component. Try next example:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTable t = new JTable(3,3);
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
    }

    private TableCellRenderer getRenderer() {
        return new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){

            private JLabel l = new JLabel();
            {
                l.setOpaque(true);
            }

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                    Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int column) {
                JComponent tableCellRendererComponent = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);
                l.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());
                l.setBorder(tableCellRendererComponent.getBorder());
                l.setBackground(tableCellRendererComponent.getBackground());
                l.setForeground(tableCellRendererComponent.getForeground());
                return l;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: The DefaultCellRenderer is a JLabel. There is no need to create another JLabel within the renderer. Just make sure you invoke super.getTableCellRenderer(...) and all the default properties will be set. The only code you need in the renderer is the formatting code.

Comment: Also, read answer/comment by @camickr, he is right about creating a new one `JLabel`.

Answer (score 2):

> in order to change the format of numbers. I have extended the DefaultTableRenderer class.

Check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easier way to customize the renderer when all you need to do is format the data. That is you should override the `setValue(...)` method instead of the `getTableCellRenderer(...)` method.